# how to create an application to read csv files without any header?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, csv

Want to create an application which reads and edits csv files without any column header and quotations.
I have coded maximum part, but it
gives error when a file without header is tested.

```
    private void LoadFile(string filePath)
    {
        Arguments arg = new Arguments();
        arg.Task = Work.task_open;
        arg.Add(BackgroundWorkArgumentKeys.openfile, filePath);
        arg.Add(BackgroundWorkArgumentKeys.setFirstRowAsHeader, true);

        this.grid.Enabled = false;

        this._BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(arg);
    }

    private void LoadFile()
    {
        this.LoadFile(this.grid.CurrentFilePath);
    }

    private void SaveFile(string filePath)
    {
        this.UpdateDataSource();

        Arguments arg = new Arguments();
        arg.Task = Work.TASK_SAVE;
        arg.Add(BackgroundWorkArgumentKeys.savefilepath, filePath);
        arg.Add(BackgroundWorkArgumentKeys.savedatasource, (DataTable)this.grid.DataSource);
        arg.Add(BackgroundWorkArgumentKeys.setFirstRowAsHeader, true);

        this.grid.Enabled = false;

        this._BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(arg);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to ignore column headings or are there none? I wrote a C program to extract data from a CSV-saved spreadsheet, and by checking the column headings the code tolerates changes to the spreadsheet such as additional columns or a different sequence.

Comment: I want the application to provide an option, as few columns don't have header in csv's.

Comment: What do you mean by without header? Are you reading a csv and saving it to some DB? Do  you want to know how it will save in case CSV has no columns name mapping to DB ?